# Downloading graphlab is causing this error

Tags: python, graphlab

This is the problem which I am getting after using `graphlab.get_dependencies`.

```
Downloading xz.
Extracting xz.
Downloading gcc-libs.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9e64085fb919> in <module>()
----> 1 graphlab.get_dependencies()

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\dependencies.pyc in get_dependencies()
     39 
     40     print('Downloading gcc-libs.')
---> 41     (dllarchive_file, dllheaders) = urllib.urlretrieve('http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-5.1.0-1-any.pkg.tar.xz')
     42     dllarchive_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
     43 

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\urllib.pyc in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data, context)
     96     else:
     97         opener = _urlopener
---> 98     return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
     99 def urlcleanup():
    100     if _urlopener:

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\urllib.pyc in retrieve(self, url, filename, reporthook, data)
    243             except IOError:
    244                 pass
--> 245         fp = self.open(url, data)
    246         try:
    247             headers = fp.info()

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\urllib.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data)
    211         try:
    212             if data is None:
--> 213                 return getattr(self, name)(url)
    214             else:
    215                 return getattr(self, name)(url, data)

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\urllib.pyc in open_http(self, url, data)
    348         if realhost: h.putheader('Host', realhost)
    349         for args in self.addheaders: h.putheader(*args)
--> 350         h.endheaders(data)
    351         errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
    352         fp = h.getfile()

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\httplib.pyc in endheaders(self, message_body)
   1036         else:
   1037             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1038         self._send_output(message_body)
   1039 
   1040     def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}):

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\httplib.pyc in _send_output(self, message_body)
    880             msg += message_body
    881             message_body = None
--> 882         self.send(msg)
    883         if message_body is not None:
    884             #message_body was not a string (i.e. it is a file) and

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\httplib.pyc in send(self, data)
    842         if self.sock is None:
    843             if self.auto_open:
--> 844                 self.connect()
    845             else:
    846                 raise NotConnected()

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\httplib.pyc in connect(self)
    819         """Connect to the host and port specified in __init__."""
    820         self.sock = self._create_connection((self.host,self.port),
--> 821                                            self.timeout, self.source_address)
    822 
    823         if self._tunnel_host:

C:\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\socket.pyc in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    573 
    574     if err is not None:
--> 575         raise err
    576     else:
    577         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Note the last line: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`. Sounds like an internet error. Is downloading any other package working?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded the ipython note book and also the Graphlab library.

Comment: Moreover i downloaded both the missing DLL and put them in Graphlab folder.  Still does not work